# How do I resoove this Mac GraalVM Error When Running JavaScript Example

Tags: graalvm

After installing the latest GraalVM on the Mac (GraalVM CE 20.1.0), and running this code segment:

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        // Context context = Context.create();
        Context context = Context.newBuilder().allowAllAccess(true).build();

        String strToEval = "print(eval('1+3'))";`
        context.eval("js", "print(eval('1+3'));");
        context.eval("js", "print(eval('Math.PI/2'));");
     }
```

I get this error:

```
java: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.oracle.truffle.dsl.processor.TruffleProcessor (in unnamed module @0xd2331f5) cannot access class com.oracle.truffle.api.dsl.Fallback (in module org.graalvm.truffle) because module org.graalvm.truffle does not export com.oracle.truffle.api.dsl to unnamed module @0xd2331f5
```

How to fix this?

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by "installing the latest GraalVM"?

Comment: Can you provide the Java launcher arguments with which you are running?

Comment: I just meant I updated to the latest version as noted above.  There are no custom Java launcher arguments other than the default ones in Intellij IDEA 2020.2. Thanks.

Comment: For some reason the tar archive contains the same file graalvm-ce-java11-20.1.0/Contents/Home/lib/graalvm/launcher-common.jar twice. And it contains graalvm-ce-java11-20.1.0/Contents/Home/lib/polyglot/polyglot_types.h with and without an extra . in the path, so also a duplicate. You can check this with the tar commandline program. I don’t know whether this makes the archive malformed. I've tried extracting using tar command, Archive utility, and Unarchiver. None produce a working JDK.